# Xamarin image download and resizing for Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

This code addresses performance issues specific to Android running Xamarin / C# when downloading images (BMP/PNG) into a listview. The caller simply specifies the URL to fetch the image from, and the preferred dimensions.

Optimisations I could do, but haven't:

- Not sure if I should use the [Android or Java namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30928912/328397)
- Stage the downloaded `byte[]` in an intermediate location - not sure if memory exhaustion is possible
- [Image caching](https://github.com/rdio/tangoandcache)
- Convert to an Android `Drawable`
- Abstract the source to be something other than a URL, e.g. the local resources
- Make a static "helper" class (not sure how to do this...)

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Content.Res;
using System.Net;

namespace validAndroid
{
    public class ImageUtils
    {
        async Task<BitmapFactory.Options> GetBitmapOptionsOfImageAsync(byte[] imageBytes)
        {
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options {
                /*Setting the InJustDecodeBounds property to true while decoding avoids memory allocation,
                 * returning null for the bitmap object but setting OutWidth, OutHeight and OutMimeType .
                 * This technique allows you to read the dimensions and type of the image data prior to
                 * construction (and memory allocation) of the bitmap.*/
                InJustDecodeBounds = true
            };

            // The result will be null because InJustDecodeBounds == true.
            Bitmap result = await BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArrayAsync (imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length -1, options);

            int imageHeight = options.OutHeight;
            int imageWidth = options.OutWidth;

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine (string.Format ("Original Size= {0}x{1}", imageWidth, imageHeight));

            return options;
        }

          static int CalculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight)
        {
            // Raw height and width of image
            float height = options.OutHeight;
            float width = options.OutWidth;
            double inSampleSize = 1D;

            if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth)
            {
                int halfHeight = (int)(height / 2);
                int halfWidth = (int)(width / 2);

                // Calculate a inSampleSize that is a power of 2 - the decoder will use a value that is a power of two anyway.
                while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth)
                {
                    inSampleSize *= 2;
                }
            }

            return (int)inSampleSize;
        }

        async Task<Android.Graphics.Bitmap> LoadScaledDownBitmapForDisplayAsync(byte[] imageBytes, BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight)
        {
            // Calculate inSampleSize
            options.InSampleSize = CalculateInSampleSize (options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

            // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
            options.InJustDecodeBounds = false;

            return await Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArrayAsync (imageBytes,0,imageBytes.Length-1,  options);
        }

        public  async  Task<Bitmap> GetImageForDisplay(string imageURL,int reqWidth, int reqHeight )
        {
            byte[] imageBytes = null;

            using (var webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                imageBytes= webClient.DownloadData(imageURL);
            }

            BitmapFactory.Options options = await GetBitmapOptionsOfImageAsync(imageBytes);
            var bitmapToDisplay = await LoadScaledDownBitmapForDisplayAsync ( imageBytes,options, reqWidth, reqHeight);
            imageBytes = null;
            return bitmapToDisplay;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`WebClient.DownloadData` is a blocking method; you should use `DownloadDataTaskAsync`. Network I/O is almost certainly the slowest part of the whole operation, so it's important that we're not blocking here. You might also want to consider using the newer `HttpClient` instead of `WebClient`.

The third parameter of `DecodeByteArrayAsync` is the length of the array, but you're passing it `imagesBytes.Length - 1`. I think you want to pass it `imageBytes.Length` instead.

There's no need to set `imageBytes` to `null`.

I don't really like that `LoadScaledDownBitmapForDisplayAsync` modifies the `options` parameter. Since the method is private it's not that important, but it is, to me, surprising behaviour. To avoid this, I would consider merging `GetBitmapOptionsOfImageAsync` and `LoadScaledDownBitmapForDisplayAsync` into one method, e.g:

```
public static async Task<Bitmap> DecodeByteArrayAsync(byte[] imageBytes, int requiredWidth, int requiredHeight)
{
    var options = new Options { InJustDecodeBounds = true };
    await BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArrayAsync(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length, options);

    options.InSampleSize = CalculateInSampleSize(options, requiredWidth, requiredHeight);
    options.InJustDecodeBounds = false;

    return await BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArrayAsync(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length, options);
}
```